# Nested ActiveRecords: Find many childrens of many parents

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2

In my Rails 3.2 app a Connector has_many Incidents.

To get all incidents of a certain connector I can do this:
(In console)

```
c = Connector.find(1) # c.class is Connector(id: integer, name: string, ...
i = c.incidents.all # all good, lists incidents of c
```

But how can I get all incidents of many connectors?

```
c = Connector.find(1,2) # works fine, but c.class is Array
i = c.incidents.all #=> NoMethodError: undefined method `incidents' for #<Array:0x4cc15e0>
```

Should be easy! But I don't get it!

Here’s the complete code in my statistics_controller.rb

```
class StatisticsController < ApplicationController
  def index

    @connectors = Connector.scoped

    if params['connector_tokens']
      logger.debug "Following tokens are given:  #{params['connector_tokens']}"
      @connectors = @connectors.find_all_by_name(params[:connector_tokens].split(','))
    end

    @start_at = params[:start_at] || 4.weeks.ago.beginning_of_week
    @end_at = params[:end_at] || Time.now


    #@time_line_data = Incident.time_line_data( @start_at, @end_at, 10) #=> That works, but doesn’t limit the result to given connectors
    @time_line_data = @connectors.incidents.time_line_data( @start_at, @end_at, 10) #=> undefined method `incidents' for #<ActiveRecord::Relation:0x3f643c8>
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # index.html.haml
    end
  end
end
```

---

### **Edit with reference to first 3 answers below:**

Great! With code below I get an array with all incidents of given connectors.

```
c = Connector.find(1,2)
i = c.map(&:incidents.all).flatten
```

But idealy I'd like to get an Active Records object instead of the array, because I'd like to call where() on it as you can see in methode `time_line_data` below.

I could reach my goal with the array, but I would need to change the whole strategy...

This is my `time_line_data()` in Incidents Model models/incidents.rb

```
      def self.time_line_data(start_at = 8.weeks.ago, end_at = Time.now, lim = 10)
        total = {}
        rickshaw = []
        arr = []
        inc = where(created_at: start_at.to_time.beginning_of_day..end_at.to_time.end_of_day)

        # create a hash, number of incidents per day, with day as key
        inc.each do |i|
          if total[i.created_at.to_date].to_i > 0
            total[i.created_at.to_date] += 1
          else
            total[i.created_at.to_date] = 1
          end
        end
        # create a hash with all days in given timeframe, number of incidents per day, date as key and 0 as value if no incident is in database for this day
        (start_at.to_date..end_at.to_date).each do |date|
          js_timestamp = date.to_time.to_i
          if total[date].to_i > 0
            arr.push([js_timestamp, total[date]])
            rickshaw.push({x: js_timestamp, y: total[date]})
          else
            arr.push([js_timestamp, 0])
            rickshaw.push({x: js_timestamp, y: 0})
          end
        end

        { :start_at => start_at,
          :end_at => end_at,
          :series => rickshaw #arr


}
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you only seem to be interested in the time line data you can further expand the map examples given before e.g.:

```
@time_line_data = @connectors.map do |connector|
  connector.incidents.map do |incident|
    incident.time_line_data(@start_at, @end_at, 10)
  end
end
```

This will map/collect all the return values of the time_line_data method call on all the incidents in the collection of connectors.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Anyway I'm afraid I need to change my whole strategy how to generate my chart data, which happens in `time_line_data`. Not such a big deal but I liked the way to do it in the model...
I updated my Question above with the code of `time_line_data`

Answer (score 2):

Ref:- [map](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Array.html#method-i-map)

```
c = Connector.find(1,2)
i = c.map(&:incidents.all).flatten
```

Comment: That works! Thanks! Also thanks to MrYoshiji! I'd like to carry on calling further `where` on i. Is there a way that i is an ActiveRecord object?

Comment: @BBQ Chef:- Happy to help, cheer's